# Gmail: automatically respond to email from different email address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am currently using my Gmail account (say, good.morning@gmail.com) to manage several other non-Gmail email accounts (for example's sake, a@a.com and b@b.com). I have emails forwarded automatically from both of those other accounts into my Gmail account. For one of those email addresses (a@a.com), I am also able to send mail through Gmail, and my account is configured to automatically respond to all mail sent to a@a.com with an email from the same address.

Due to institutional policies governing b.com's email account (lack of SMTP access), I can forward mail to Gmail but am unable to send mail as b@b.com from my Gmail account. I would therefore like to reply to all mail sent to b@b.com with an email sent from my account a@a.com. *Is there any way to do set that up automatically in Gmail?*

Sorry so long.

Comment: I removed underscore `_` from your example email id and put a dot `.` there, as Gmail doesn't support `_`.

Comment: Can you auto-forward messages from b@b to a@a? If so, at that point, would your auto-response message from a@a work?

Comment: Not through b.com; the same institutional policies that preclude my sending mail through their SMTP servers seem to preclude auto-forwarding to an email account outside of their domain. I tried to set up an auto-forwarding filter within gmail itself, but in addition to being a remarkably clumsy solution, it doesn't seem to be working -- emails are just getting dropped. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to respond an email with an external email address you need access to the SMTP servers of the external email address as Gmail policies doesn't allow to send email from external addresses from their own email servers for security reasons.

**References**
[Send mail from a different address or alias - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

Answer (score -3):

Create a filter for all incoming email to that address and apply a canned response to all emails sent to that address.

Comment: Its better to tell the steps to do all this.

Comment: As @serenesat said, an answer is most useful when it includes the steps on how to accomplish the solution.